Voltage controlled relay with very wide input range
I'm still a beginner, but one thing I've gotten used to making is a simple switch circuit that goes like this:
Voltage input -> FET -> 10A Electromechanical relay
Voltage input is usually 3V3 or 5V, and the relay runs on 12V. So there are many FETs that will do that job without any more logic.
But I want a voltage-controlled relay circuit that accepts a very wide range of voltages. Something like 3V3-70V is what I'm looking for. 1V8-100V would be even better. I do not know how to do this.
There are plenty of FETs that can accept a V_gs of 3-70V. But with relay voltage fixed, V_gd could be anything from -9 to 48 or more. If I knew Vin would be less than relay voltage, I could just downregulate it. And a regulator with that wide a range isn't cheap, though maybe that's the cost of solving this problem.
Edits:
The input is independent of the relay power. The relay power comes from a 12V power supply. Probably a rack-mounted Keysight or Chroma.
The input range is so wide because this is for test equipment to be used on a system that has voltages ranging from 1v8 to 70V. I could make multiple versions of the board, but that means more multiple part numbers, more design reviews, multiple PCBA orders, multiple CAD models, and just overall more time and money.
I could make the board adjustable, but then I have to trust people to adjust it. That may just be the best option.
Input needs to be high-impedance, which is why FETs are so appealing. But a FET isn't required as the strategy.
This is my usual basic strategy for this problem, except that usually I expect the INPUT_POS to be between +3V3 and +12V.


Are you really asking for a circuit where the input might be 3.3v and might be 100 and we don't know which?  As a control signal?  Could you fill in a bit more about this?  It sounds like a pretty strange problem that might be more easily solved at another point in your system, rather than solving this FET problem.

Is the input voltage range independend of the fixed 12 V relay coil supply?

Maybe not that important, but what is the solenoid current of your relay? And how much control input current do you expect, what is the expected range of input currents you want this to work over? Also, do you need galvanic isolation between input and relay solenoid? Can they use common ground?

Can you include a simple block schematic of what you want to do and how you want to connect it?

@jonathanjo, I agree this is probably a misunderstanding of spec, but alas it is not that strange or unexpected! Avionics equipment often has "discrete inputs/outputs", basically GPIO, that run off the battery voltage. This is nominally 24-28V, but can drop to 6-8V during loads and 80+V during load dump.  The spec requires that it "outputs" effectively the battery voltage, and reads as "input" voltages which are quite low. It's been a few years, so i'm fuzzy on the details

Your MOSFET is connected in the wrong way. Compare it to my schematic.

@rohmeooo I am, in fact, working with avionics. I looked back to see if I happened to have mentioned it, but no -- you guessed it in one. Goal is transition from software to EE (and back in school for it).

@EdinFifić Do you mean that I should put the load on the high side? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Just a warning about the specs: if you have a high-impedance input that is sensitive to small voltages (like 1.8 V) and the wiring runs close to signals that reach 100 V, capacitive coupling can easily cause enough noise to cause false activation.

@Jason Yes, the MOSFET source goes to ground, the load goes between positive supply and drain of the MOSFET.

@jpa Yes, you're right, that's one thing I forgot to mention in my circuit because I focused on the lowest input currents, not knowing that it might include long wires in a noisy environment. In that case he can use much lower input resistances to reduce the effect of wire coupling.

(EDIT: As user "jpa" mentions in his comment, if you have long control signal wires in a noisy environment, the input resistances I used below would be too high, and false triggering could occur due to the currents induced in the wires.
A simple solution to that problem is to reduce the input resistor values, but then you increase the load on the control signal source and waste more energy in heat.
If you reduce the R1 resistor to 10kΩ and R2 to 100kΩ, you will make it 10 times less sensitive to noise, but the R1 will be dissipating almost 1W in heat at a 100V input signal while about 10mA current runs through it, so it would have to be rated for at least 1.5W to give it a margin of safety.
At the same time, the input capacitor C1 value can be increased to 1uF to reduce stray AC voltages and spikes even more.
The best thing to do would be to start with my schematic below and use an oscilloscope with at least 10:1 probes to see whether the induced voltages need to be further reduced. Even a voltmeter may help - the DC voltage without a control signal being ON should never reach the threshold of turning the transistor and the relay ON.)

 This is doable with either a MOSFET or a BJT, and you don't need a comparator or any fancy circuit, just a way to limit the applied gate-source voltage, and this can be fairly simple.  
Below is a sort of a circuit that might work for you.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The resistor R1 serves to limit the current through the 5V zener diode D1 which limits the maximum voltage appearing on the gate of the MOSFET.
The capacitor serves to absorb voltage spikes and bypass noise which may appear on the input.
The resistor R2 serves to keep the floating input close to zero volts, but it doesn't significantly reduce the input voltage.
The MOSFET model in this schematic can be turned on with even less than 1.5V.
Diode D2 protects the MOSFET from the relay solenoid's inductive kickback during MOSFET turnoff.
A similar thing can be done with a BJT, which can get turned on at less than 1V, as you know.
The schematic below shows how it may be done.

simulate this circuit
As you can see, there is no need for a zener diode because the forward-biased base-emitter PN junction does the job of limiting the input voltage to less than 1V.
The capacitor serves to bypass any noise on the input.
R2 serves to ensure the transistor being off with no input signal.
In order to increase the total amplification and thus be able to keep the same high input resistance value of 100kΩ, we need to add another transistor, which is the PNP Q2 here.
R4 serves to keep it off when transistor Q1 is off, while R3 limits the current between the two transistors.
NOTE: Depending on the current of the relay coil, R3 may need to be reduced to 4.7kΩ. Also, R1 may be too high at the lowest input voltage to provide sufficient current to Q1, and thus to Q2.
These resistor values don't need to be changed if you use transistors with higher hFE (beta or amplification); 2N3904 and 2N3906 hFE is typically around 100 or even more, but it may be as low as 40.
Some other transistors with a guaranteed minimum hFE of at least 200 would work more reliably (you wouldn't worry about them not providing sufficient current at the lowest input voltage(s).

@user3642638 Values may be adjusted depending on solenoid current, input resistance/impedance required, transistor models used, etc.

I am actually learning a ton from the second version. The first one makes sense to me, though I hadn't thought to use a zener that way. The second one needs more study.
I'm so glad I decided to go into HW. Software just isn't this fun.

@Jason I am glad about that. That's why we're here, to teach and learn from each other, and help when we get stuck. There is PLENTY to learn, so you should never be bored, as long as you want to know more. If you want to have an LED indicating control signal, let me know and I will see how to include it in the schematic.

@Jason There's something about the high you get when you come up with some novel and elegant circuit. Way better than a clever bit of code! And when you look at some spaghetti schematic full of transistors, or the simplest of designs with some twist you never considered before, the moment you understand it, that's something else again. I have never had that degree of elation from any software project.


I want a voltage-controlled relay circuit that accepts a very wide range of voltages.

There's a wide variety of solutions that are possible. Here's one: a common-emitter low-side driver for the relay, driven from a constant voltage clamp.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The input- and relay current vs. control voltage:

The power dissipation on Q1 and Q2 as a function of control voltage:

Right now, the input current is constant over a wide voltage range, so the incremental resistance of the input when the relay is turned on is infinite. You can lower the control current by replacing Q1 with a pseudo-Darlington driving the high side of the relay.

Like Edin's second response above, I struggle a bit more with any BJT based circuit as compared with a FET based one. I just don't have the same intuition for them yet. That means I learn more from the answer, which is a benefit. But I won't pretend to fully understand it yet. I think mostly in terms of voltages and not currents.
I really appreciate the circuitlab links. I went ahead and signed up so I can save them and play with my own versions of the circuits. It's been edifying.

What happens if the input is floating?

@EdinFifić After a little adjustment to the base bias network: nothing much happens, the relay is off :) Thank you for noticing that.
